# Unable to load a .png image to a rectangle shape in Slick2D (In Java)

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm trying to add a "grass.png" image onto a rectangle (it's a tile sprite) so the rectangle has a texture instead of a plain green colour.

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException 
{
        renderBackground(g);
}

private void renderBackground(Graphics g) throws SlickException 
{
        //Attempt to load textures to the rectangle
        Shape rectangle = null;
        Image groundTexture = new Image("res/grassMid.png");
        g.texture(rectangle, groundTexture);
        g.draw(rectangle);
}
```

It gives the error `java.lang.NullPointerException`. May I know where did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you try `"grassMid.png"`? or `new image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/grassMid.png"), "grassMid.png");` (from the class path)

Comment: It shouldn't matter because I tried loading my background with the similar steps and it worked: ```Image gameBackground = new Image("res/GameBackground.jpg");

gameBackground = gameBackground.getScaledCopy(0.55f);

gameBackground.draw(0, -170);```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by just using `fillRect`:

```
    Shape rectangle = null;
    Image groundTexture = new Image("res/grassMid.png");

    //parameters are x position, y position, width, height, image, offsetX, offsetY
    g.fillRect(0.0f, Window.HEIGHT * 5.3f / 6.0f, (float) Window.WIDTH, Window.HEIGHT / 8.0f, groundTexture, 50, 0);
```